# Webpack 4 splitChunks generating multiple css

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

I'm trying to generate multiple css using webpack 4 min-css-extract-plugin and splitChunks plugin.

Here is my webpack config.

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = [{
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "./dist")),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: false,
        commons: {
          name: 'commons',
          test: /.styl$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
          minChunks: 1,
        },
        englishStyle: {
          name: 'styles_en',
          test: (c) => {
            return c.type.match(/mini-css-extract-plugin/) && c._identifier.indexOf('_ar') === -1;
          },
          chunks: 'all',
          priority: 1,
          enforce: true,
        },
        arabicStyles: {
          name: 'styles_ar',
          test: (c) => {
            return c.type.match(/mini-css-extract-plugin/) && c._identifier.indexOf('_ar') !== -1;
          },
          priority: 1,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        }
      }
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "stylus-loader"
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[name].css"
    })
  ]
}]
```

and here is my css file structure.

```
common.styl
  ...

style.styl 
  @import common.styl
  ...

style_ar.styl
  @import common.styl
  ...

index.js
 import styles from style.styl
 import styles from style_ar.styl
```

The above configuration is generating only two files styles_ar.css and style.css. with common content in both the files.

How do I generate a separate a file for common file?

If I give priority to commons cacheGroup It will generate only one file commons.styl.

Comment: This is an interesting question and I even have tried to start a bounty on it but at last moment I got  that answer would be "webpack doens't add any value in this case - use stylus directly"... Can you explain what you expect from using webpack for css ? and how you would speed up dev process - recompile css on js changes?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn how it works. Actually there are lot of advantages for using webpack for css. Eg: In my case I have standalone widgets/components in pages. I just import that component and use in the react render method without worrying about loading the styles of that component.

Comment: didn't get which advantages of webpack+MiniCssExtractPlugin you are mentionig. what webpack+MiniCssExtractPlugin can add for react comenents that gulp file that starts stylus couldn't do? this is important to understand. is this only "level of comfort", "less code" or something else?

Comment: in fact, react SPA is the case when I'm quite sure that you do not need to use MiniCssExtractPlugin (exctract css and link it separatly) at all...

Comment: did you fix this problem and how to fix it? @SAGAR TALLA

Answer (score -2):

This is a kind of "negative" answer but if you will point me that I miss something - I will drop it.

1) css though MiniCssExtractPlugin is a kind of trick that people uses to do not create gulp file for generating css files - they want just to keep everithing in one place (and write less code). why this is possible - all is ok - but do not forget this is still a trick.

Is this your motivation? Or in real life you need to include highly specific webpack plugins into css production process? I'm not talking about autoprefixer - you can use post-css from gulp also. But something really webpack specific? May be some webpack runtime features?

2) This is not a good idea to "force" a trick to be something more than trick.

Note: we are not cover the case when you want to create "one mixed bundle for css and js" - that means use `css-loader` without `MiniCssExtractPlugin` - it would be a totally different story.

So the answer is: use stylus directly to generate a chunked css you want.

Or try "more heavy tricks": https://github.com/faceyspacey/extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin